# Symfony2 Doctrine ORM Composite Primary Keys

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, composite-primary-key

I am developing an application in **Symfony 2.3** with **Doctrine 2.4** as ORM. The database engine I use is **PostgreSQL**. I'm having problems when mapping entities with composite primary keys in other tables. 
These keys are foreign keys in the related key.

The tables in my database have the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE public.establecimiento
(
  id_establecimiento integer NOT NULL,
  establecimiento character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_establecimiento PRIMARY KEY (id_establecimiento )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
CREATE TABLE public.establecimiento_sec
(
  id_establecimiento_sec integer NOT NULL,
  id_establecimiento integer NOT NULL,
  det_seccion character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  plano character varying(100),
  sector_ingreso character varying(254),
  sponsor_imagen_sec character varying(96000),
  CONSTRAINT pk_establecimientos_sec PRIMARY KEY (id_establecimiento_sec , id_establecimiento ),
  CONSTRAINT fk_establec_reference_establec FOREIGN KEY (id_establecimiento)
      REFERENCES public.establecimiento (id_establecimiento) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
CREATE TABLE public.establecimiento_sec_plano
(
  id_establecimiento_sec_plano integer NOT NULL,
  id_establecimiento_sec integer NOT NULL,
  id_establecimiento integer NOT NULL,
  det_plano character varying(512),
  cantidad integer NOT NULL,
  precio double precision,
  insert_charge double precision DEFAULT 0,
  descr character varying(254),
  CONSTRAINT pk_establecimiento_sec_plano PRIMARY KEY (id_establecimiento_sec_plano , id_establecimiento_sec , id_establecimiento ),
  CONSTRAINT fk_establecimiento_sec FOREIGN KEY (id_establecimiento, id_establecimiento_sec)
      REFERENCES public.establecimiento_sec (id_establecimiento, id_establecimiento_sec) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Defining the entity establecimientoSecPlano, $establecimientoSec variable containing the keys $establecimiento and $id_establecimiento_sec

//Entity/EstablecimientosSecPlano

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticketway\PruebaBundle\Entity\EstablecimientosSec")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns(
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_establecimiento_sec", referencedColumnName="id_establecimiento_sec"),
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_establecimiento", referencedColumnName="id_establecimiento")) 
 */
private $establecimientoSec;
```

//Entity/EstablecimientosSec

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticketway\PruebaBundle\Entity\Establecimientos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_establecimiento", referencedColumnName="id_establecimiento") 
 */
private $establecimiento;
```

When executing the command doctrine: mapping: import I get the following error

**[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  It is not possible to map entity 'EstablecimientoSec' with a composite primary key as part of the primary key of another entity 'EstablecimientoSecPlano#idEstablecimiento'.**

I wonder if there is any way to define the entities in symfony and I can not do with doctrine.

Can I map the features in another way for the application to work correctly?

I hope my question is understood. thanks

Comment: Any odds this helps? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Comment: probe that solution but without success, thanks anyway @Denis

Comment: You *could* work around this by assigning independent, auto-generated, single-column IDs for all tables and use `id_establecimiento_sec_plano`, `id_establecimiento_sec`, and `id_establecimiento` as fields. (you do not need to have the same field in multiple tables/entities as you can access those using the relation). I.e. *if* I understand your problem correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into this problem because your composite foreign key is another table's composite primary key. This is not a good development practice, which is why it is simply not supported by Doctrine, and I strongly doubt that it ever will be.

**Solution 1 (preferred):**

Add a single, auto-increment primary key to `EstablecimientosSec`. You can then link to that `EstablecimientosSec.id` instead.

**Solution 2:**

If changing the database structure is absolutely not possible, do not map the relationship. Instead, you can fetch the related `EstablecimientosSec` entities in a separate query using the composite primary key. It's not a prefect solution, but it works under these constraints. Tip: avoid querying the related objects as part of a loop.

Comment: Sorry for later answer, finally I used the Solution 1. Thanks!